# How to debug deeplinks/universal links from a killed app state in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, ios-universal-links, flutter-deep-link

I'm developing an app that uses deeplinks (myapp://products) and universal links (https://myapp.com/products) and routes to certain views based on the URL path components.

While I've tested this on my device when backgrounded, I'm unable to test the same functionality while the app is killed and booted upon tapping a deeplink/universal link, as the debugger doesn't stay attached when I kill the app on the device and it's running in VSCode.

Is there some solution that allows the debugger to remain attached if the app is killed?

Answer (score 0):

I've discovered that if in VSCode you run the app in release mode, when you kill the app on the device (by swiping it up to close it), the debugger remains attached. While breakpoints don't work, you can follow along by using print commands to the console.